# WPF ListBox Selection Problem when changing an item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

When changing the selected item in a ListBox, I'm getting a weird error where the changed item appears selected but I cannot deselect it or reselect it.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's a sample app that demonstrates the problem.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new WindowViewModel();
        lst.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((WindowViewModel)this.DataContext).Items[0] = "New Item";
    }
}

public class WindowViewModel
{
    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Items.Add("Item1");
        Items.Add("Item2");
        Items.Add("Item3");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfSelectionIssue.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Change" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ListBox x:Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[ImageOfIssue http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/9396/wpfselectionissue.jpg](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/9396/wpfselectionissue.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching a bit more I found the solution. Adding an IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to the ListBox solved the problem.

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lst" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem where I couldn't deselect any items. It seems that the listbox doesn't understand when you have multiple items in the list which are exactly the same. (And thus it selects them all, but doesn't deselect them)

This also happens when you change the value of the selected item when your binding. You have to first deselect the index (ex: listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;) and then change the value.

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a good answer though and I personally would not be happy with it, so I had a go and found an alternative.

This situation only occurs IF the item you are changing is currently selected and you are binding directly to the source.

Use a `CollectViewSource` between the `ListBox` and your view model.

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Items}" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Change" Click="Button_Click" />
    <ListBox x:Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Can't explain what is going on in your example, may be a bug with WPF, but this is a better/cleaner solution. I suspect `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` is creating a view source for you behind-the-scenes and that is why it works.

HTH,

Comment: The problem is with the SelectedItems, not the ItemsSource.

Comment: So why don't you like using IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem?